# Dropping Stream events if consumer isn't fast enough

Tags: flutter, dart

The following snippet is the "driver" for decoding an MJPEG-stream received via HTTP. It splits the incoming data stream into individual JPEG-frames (`_mjpegSplitter`) and then decodes each frame into a `dart:ui` image (`_decodeFrame`).

Please note that `_decodeFrame` runs the decoder in a separate Isolate and returns a `Future<Image>` that resolves once the image is ready.

```
class MJPEGImageStream extends Stream<ui.Image> {
  MJPEGImageStream(this.url);

  final String url;
 
  final _httpClient = Client();

  @override
  StreamSubscription<ui.Image> listen(void Function(ui.Image event)? onData, {Function? onError, void Function()? onDone, bool? cancelOnError}) {
    final request = Request("GET", Uri.parse(url));
    var decoding = false;

    return Stream.fromFuture(_httpClient.send(request).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30)))
        .asyncExpand((response) {
          if (response.statusCode < 200 && response.statusCode >= 300) {
            throw HttpException('Stream returned ${response.statusCode} status');
          }
          return response.stream;
        })
        .transform(_mjpegSplitter)
        .asyncMap((frame) async {
          if (decoding) {
            // skip frame if still decoding
            return null;
          }
          decoding = true;
          try {
            return await _decodeFrame(frame);
          } finally {
            decoding = false;
          }
        })
        .where((_) => _ != null) // remove skipped frame
        .cast<ui.Image>() // turn ui.Image? into ui.Image
        .listen(onData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: cancelOnError);
  }
}
```

However, sometimes the data sent from the server isn't decoded fast enough by the client, resulting in a build-up of video-lag. So, I'd like to drop incoming frames if decoding of a frame is still on-going.

To symbolise that in the code, I added a naive `decoding` flag, but of course that doesn't work since the stream runs each `asyncMap` one-by-one, waiting for the future in-between.

So, how can I build a stream that drops events if the downstream isn't consuming fast enough?

Comment: The conversion done by _decodeFrame is already running in a separate isolate.

Comment: @pskink I edited the Q

Comment: I just looked into the code of asyncMap. It pauses the stream. I think I could just write a version that drops instead of pausing...

Comment: indeed [asyncMapSample](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/AsyncMap/asyncMapSample.html) is much better, the docs say: *"Like asyncMap but events are discarded while work is happening in convert."*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out meanwhile by adapting `Stream.asyncMap`. The following "lossy" version will drop data events from the source while an async conversion is still running.

```
extension StreamExt<T> on Stream<T> {
  ///
  /// Like `Stream.asyncMap`, but if `convert` returns a `Future`, all further data events from the source are dropped until the `Future` resolved.
  ///
  Stream<E> lossyAsyncMap<E>(FutureOr<E> Function(T event) convert) {
    final controller = StreamController<E>(sync: true);

    var waiting = false;

    controller.onListen = () {
      final subscription = listen(null, onError: controller.addError, onDone: controller.close);

      final resume = subscription.resume;
      subscription.onData((T event) {
        if (waiting) {
          return;
        }
        FutureOr<E> newValue;
        try {
          newValue = convert(event);
        } catch (e, s) {
          controller.addError(e, s);
          return;
        }
        if (newValue is Future<E>) {
          waiting = true;
          newValue.then(controller.add, onError: controller.addError).whenComplete(() => waiting = false);
        } else {
          controller.add(newValue);
        }
      });
      controller.onCancel = subscription.cancel;
      controller
        ..onPause = subscription.pause
        ..onResume = resume;
    };
    return controller.stream;
  }
}
```